# Not receiving Push Notifications on Android

Tags: android, push-notification, pushsharp

I am not receiving my Android Push notifications. I am able to

- register the device
- receive a device identifier
- push the notification message to GCM

I successfully enter into the Notification Sent event, but no message is received on my device. The successful push code is as follows:

```
string apiKey = "API KEY HERE";
push.RegisterGcmService(new GcmPushChannelSettings(apiKey));

string load = "Hello World";
int count = 2;
string dev = 'device identifier generated for device';
string payload = "{\"alert\":" + "\"" + load + "\"" + ",\"badge\":" + "\"" + count + "\"}";
//IMPORTANT: For Android you MUST use your own RegistrationId here that gets generated within your Android app itself!
GcmNotification note = new GcmNotification().ForDeviceRegistrationId(dev).WithJson(payload);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have everything set up on the android side.
https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html

Besides that, PushSharp does have a new version available that you may want to get. 
https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp

You may also want to add some events to track and make sure there are no issues.

```
        push.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired += new DeviceSubscriptionExpiredDelegate(push_OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired);
        push.OnDeviceSubscriptionChanged += new DeviceSubscriptionChangedDelegate(push_OnDeviceSubscriptionChanged);
        push.OnChannelException += new ChannelExceptionDelegate(push_OnChannelException);
        push.OnNotificationFailed += new NotificationFailedDelegate(push_OnNotificationFailed);
        push.OnNotificationSent += new NotificationSentDelegate(push_OnNotificationSent);
```

Then on the android side, check logcat to see if any messages are coming through.

Even stepping back and try to send a push from the device itself.
https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Comment: It seems there is something that needs to be done on the android app side in order to display them onto the phone once it is received by GCM. I found that the messages were pushed to GCM and GCM sent them but the android app is not handling the message for display.  Thank you for your help.